# Display label data in array to output panel -- actionscript 3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, label, flash-cs5

I try to build simple program, this is my code :

```
//first program 
trace("data");  //data --> can display label "data".
//second program
var dot:Dot = new Dot(); //graphic from library
trace(dot);   //[object Dot]    --> Cant show label "dot" ??
```

On first program with trace(); i can see label "data" in output panel, but on second program i cant see label 'dot' in output panel, my question is how to see the label data like first program, and if i push 'dot' in array how can i see the 'dot' label if the data type of 'dot' is movieclip or graphic??
Thanks,.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your question, because I can't see any advantage in having `dot` in your output window vs `[object Dot]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var dot:Dot = new Dot(); //graphic from library
dot.name = "dot";
trace(dot.name);
```

Comment: Thank guys..
this is what i am looking for.. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

In your class `Dot` you can add a [`toString()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html#toString%28%29) method:

```
public class Dot extends MovieClip
{
    public function toString():String
    {
        return 'dot';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marty, but 'Dot' is not class, dot is a graphic.

Comment: @D2N That's fine, if you create this class and have it in the root directory, it will get picked up by your symbol.